# How to pass host pointers in to mapped device memory without copying host data?

Tags: c, opencl, gpgpu

I'm new to C, C++ and OpenCL. I have two questions.

(1) If I have a number of host input data variables such as long and double arrays is there any way to avoid copying each one to the device (in the traditional OpenCL way i.e. createBuffer etc) and instead simply map some memory from the device into the host and write host pointers into the device memory to then access within the kernel? I'm told there is but I cannot figure out the code to do this.

Below I have an example input data array. The objective is to somehow relay a pointer to it to the device without copying it in any way as the various input data variables could be very large. I allocate a buffer, enqueue a map buffer, get a device pointer back but then I'm unsure of how to pass the input to that device pointer. I've used a type of cl_long for the device pointer which may be wrong.

```
cl_long inputData[2] = {1,2};

cl_mem inputBuffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, 
        sizeof(cl_long) * 2, NULL, NULL);

cl long* inputMap = (cl_long*) clEnqueueMapBuffer(
        queue, inputBuffer, TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, 
        sizeof(cl_long) * 2, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);

// what to do here?

clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(queue, inputBuffer, inputMap, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

I've used space for two cl_longs above but in reality if I'm passing pointers to host data what would I allocate here?

(2) What about packing pointers to more than one input variable into the same memory space returned by clEnqueueMapBuffer? Let's say I have a long array and a double array can I pass pointers to both of them into the same piece of mapped device memory?

I would really appreciate some example source code with particular elaboration on host and device memory and how they are kept in sync as well as on pointers as I'm a bit new to them.

P.S. I have seen another example on SO of writing host data into device mapped memory (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673794/opencl-mapped-memory-doesnt-work) but again it uses a manual write of data into the memory equivalent to copying.

UPDATE: In response to Raj's comment (replying here in case my comment is too long) I've already begun using that flag but probably have a mistake in my pointer code somewhere.

```
double a[2] = { 3.0, 6.0 } ;
size_t pointerSize = sizeof(double*);

cl_mem bufA = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR, pointerSize, NULL, NULL);
clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &bufA);

double* pA = (double*) clEnqueueMapBuffer(queue, bufA, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_WRITE, 0, pointerSize, 0, NULL, NULL, &err);
*pA = *a;
```

At this point if I print a[0] and a[1] in the kernel itself I get:

```
a[0]=3.000000
a[1]=-0.000000
```

a[1] is obviously wrong. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the answer would be to create a buffer using `clCreateBuffer` and passing this parameter `CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR`

Check out this description [OpenCL create Buffer API](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html)

On CUDA Architecture it is similar to `cudaHostAlloc`. `cudaHostAlloc` will allocate memory on host, which is also accessible to the GPU Device. More information about the same can be found on this [Webpage](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_2/rel/toolkit/docs/online/group__CUDART__MEMORY_g15a3871f15f8c38f5b7190946845758c.html)

Comment: Thanks Raj. I just started using that flag moments before reading your answer. But my logic is still not working. I've posted a code update under my original post. Would you please take a look?

Comment: Before reading the code, did you check for one thing. Sometimes, with some GPU's it is not possible to allocate the memory on the host. It is because the GPU is not supporting it. Does your GPU support this kind of memory allocations? 
Also I suggest you to do the error checking, to see what is going wrong. You can try to print the error code, if there is any.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check this but it's a radeon 7900 series supporting opencl 1.2. And it does work with a[0] but just not with the array as a whole i.e. not a[1]. I'm guessing it's a code error.

Comment: In you code you should change `size_t pointerSize = sizeof(double*);
` to `size_t pointerSize = 2 *sizeof(double);` and it should work. :)

and also you should have `*(pA +1) = *(a + 1 )` ?

Comment: Tried it. Still not working. The reason I set that to sizeof(double*) is because I only wanted enough space for one pointer - a pointer to the start of the array 'a'. I thought the device would reference the host memory for the actual array. I'm wondering if it's anything to do with the code: `*pA = *a`. This sets p to the first element of a but what I really wanted to do was set it to a pointer to the first element. I'm not sure if I'm doing this right.

Comment: Regarding `*(pA +1) = *(a + 1 )` (which appeared later in your comment) that does work. However I wanted this to be dynamic. If you imagine a case where there are vectors of arbitrary sizes and all I have are references like &vec[0] and I want to send such a pointer to the device I won't be able to manually link every element to the device. I just want to send a pointer to the first element and want to be able to reference all the elements using indices.

Comment: Lets clarify first `a = array on your host` then `bufA = array on host and device common` and finally `pA pointing to bufA`. Now when you say `*pA = *a` you are copying from host array A element 0 to bufA which is on host and device both. if you do `*(pA +1) = *(a+1)` will copy the second element. In general you should do a `memcpy(pA, a, 2*sizeof(double))` It will copy all the elements from a to pA or bufA. I hope that is what you want.

Comment: Raj. Thanks for your help. I'll use memcpy for now which works. If I find a better way I'll let you know. What I wanted was to avoid copying of data and I wanted the kernel to use pointers to host data but I'm not even sure that this is possible to be honest.

Comment: I think its possible. bufA and pA are pointing to the same memory locations. You just need to pass the bufA pointer to the kernel. thats all i would say. :)

Comment: perfect @Raj worked for me too.. map buffer to get the data from device and memcpy for sending the data to device. using AMD OpenCl CPU implementation. +1 to ur comment.